# How to get actual scrollLeft of a element when using "scroll-behavior: smooth"

Tags: javascript, css

I'm setting in javascript the `scrollLeft` property of a element, but in next line when I try to get the value back, I'm getting 0 as a return.

This is due to me using "scroll-behavior: smooth" in the scrollable element.

See in codepen: https://codepen.io/lucaswxp/pen/VwZOZqX

Or here

HTML:

```html
<div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">
  <div class="large-content"></div>
</div>

<pre id="history"></pre>
```

JS:

```js
const scrollable = document.getElementById('scrollable')
const history = document.getElementById('history')

scrollable.scrollLeft += 500

history.innerText += `current scrollLeft: ${scrollable.scrollLeft}` // here I get zero!!!

setTimeout(() => history.innerText += `\ncurrent scrollLeft: ${scrollable.scrollLeft}`, 1000) // after timeout, it works!
```

CSS

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.large-content{
  width: 30000px;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can see that only after the setTimeout I can get the correct value, this is because of the animation being over. How can I get the actual value WITHOUT computing it on my side? I don't want to keep track of scroll position.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Use callback and setInterval

```html
<style>
 .scrollable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }

 .large-content {
  width: 30000px;
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
 }
</style>
<script>
 window.onload = function () {
  var scrollable = document.getElementById('scrollable');
  var history = document.getElementById('history');
  scroll(scrollable, 5000, function (value) {
   console.log("Scroll finished (in " + value + " px)");
  });
 }

 function scroll(elm, sl, callback) {
  var finish = elm.scrollLeft + sl;
  elm.scrollLeft = finish;
  var cicle = setInterval(function(e = elm, c = callback) {
   if (e.scrollLeft == finish) {
    c(e.scrollLeft);
    clearInterval(cicle);
   }
  }, 50);
 }
</script>
<div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">
 <div class="large-content"></div>
</div>
<pre id="history"></pre>
```

Comment: This has the same problem, the final value will only be available AFTER the animation as completed.

Comment: Now is fired after complete animation.